# pyautogui print screen from any video sources

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to take a screen shot using `pyautogui` and save the file locally.

```
import pyautogui
def printScreen():
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.show()
    return myScreenshot
```

But it takes only from my **first video source**, but I have 3 monitors.
How can I take a **screenshot** for all videos and stack the image side by side?

Is there a way to stack the images not using `opencv` or a heavy lib?

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui.screenshot()` is taking screenshoot of main screen only.

If you want to use pyautogui to capture also something from other displays you can use its `pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))` function, but in this case you will need to get window top-left corner coordinates and window size -  `region` takes 4-integer tuple as argument (left, top, width, height).

If you want to get mouse coordinates you can use for example:

`pyautogui.position()` which  will return (x, y), but it will be still necessery to calculate window width and height. So in fact you will need coordinates of top-left corner and bottom-right corner.

Because:

```
width = int(bottom_right_x) - int(top_left_x)
height = int(bottom_right_y) - int(top_left_y)
```

This will help to understand it:

```
0,0       X increases -->
+---------------------------+
|                           | Y increases
|                           |     |
|   1920 x 1080 screen      |     |
|                           |     V
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+ 1919, 1079
```

In your case I would suggest automate the process of getting windows coordinates from which you want to take screenshoot.
I wrote a program to ilustrate it, if you don't understand something - leave a comment. 
For merging the images you will find some simple solutions for sure.

Try this:

```
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import win32com.client
import mouse
import time


window_amount = int(input("type how many windows you want to capture\n"))
hwnd_list = []

# get the hwnds of windows you want to capture screenshoot from
for i in range(window_amount):
    print('activate the ' + str(i+1) + ' window by clicking its icon on the taskbar')
    mouse.wait(button='left', target_types=('down', 'double'))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    hwnd_list.append(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    print("list of window hwnds: " + str(hwnd_list))

# get the windows coordinates and take a screenshoot
for i in range(window_amount):
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys('%')
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_list[i])
    x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd_list[i])
    x, y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd_list[i], (x, y))
    x1, y1 = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd_list[i], (x1 - x, y1 - y))
    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, x1, y1))
    im.show()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

You can also use different then `pyautogui` module to capture all displays at once or the whole screen of selected display. 
For example `mss`: https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html

Wthout doing a screenshoot only of specific windows you can simplify the process, but I don't know if that's your point.

Comment: id like to make it independent of mouse position. and in windows and linux

Comment: That's the second part with the program example about.

Comment: im having aproblem in my ubuntu pyoutgui only works if i run this command in terminal `sudo xhost +` how to fix it ?